# hot reload во Flutter 2 не обновляет приложение в Android Studio

Tags: flutter

В Андроид Студио запускаю приложение, написанное на Флаттере, потом изменяю код, в консоле показывается, что Хот Релоад срабатывает но само приложение не обновляется, ни в эмуляторе, ни на реальном устройстве. Недавно обновил Флаттер до второй версии, все работало, просто вдруг перестало работать резко ни с того ни с сего))) Помогите пожалуйста, что делать, где настроить??? Может я плохо искал, но никто вроде не сталкивался с такой проблемой... кэши чистил, не помогает...

Windows 10, Android Studio 4, Flutter 2

(Не знаю, как задать вопрос на английском.)

```
C:\Users\NITROGEN\AndroidStudioProjects\calendar>flutter doctor -v
```

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.867], locale ru-RU)

- Flutter version 2.0.2 at C:\flutter
- Framework revision 8962f6dc68 (4 days ago), 2021-03-11 13:22:20 -0800
- Engine revision 5d8bf811b3
- Dart version 2.12.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)

- Android SDK at C:\Users\NITROGEN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
- Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
- Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
- Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
  1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
- All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)

- Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
- Flutter plugin can be installed from:
  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
- Dart plugin can be installed from:
  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
- Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
  1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.54.2)

- VS Code at C:\Users\NITROGEN\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
- Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)

- SM G973F (mobile) • RF8M33HDZMR • android-arm64 • Android 11 (API 30)

No issues found!

Comment: Для начала что говорит flutter doctor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая же проблема была, решил переустановкой:

1. Скачал заново SDK [отсюда](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)
2. Удалил папку `flutter` с диска
3. Распаковал скачанное туда, где удалил папку `flutter`
4. Далее, перешёл в папку `bin` и запустил два файла - `dart.bin` и `flutter.bin`
5. После всех манипуляций прописал в командной строке следующую команду `flutter doctor`

P.S. Когда проект откроешь, в консоле пропиши две команды - `flutter clean`, а затем `flutter pub get`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробую, отпишусь о результате

Comment: Да, спасибо вам, похоже переустановка всего и вся помогла